# How to add pagination to list/grid view in php, bootstrap, css?

Tags: php, html, css, pagination

I am working on a search page which has an option of list and grid view. Now I want to add pagination to the same. Not sure how to add it to this code.

Also there's a bug in this page, which is - when I refresh the page I can see both the views, one followed by the other.
It only works when I click on a particular button (list or grid).

```
$searchData = Schema::searchVideo($searchValue);
<div class="container">
    <div class="card border-light mb-3 text-center">
<div class="row">
        <?php
        if (empty($searchData)) {
            echo <<<HTML
            <div class="alert alert-danger col-md-12 col-md-offset-4" role="alert" align="center">
                No videos matched the search
            </div>
HTML;
        } else {

  <div id="container">
     <div class="well well-sm"> 
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button id="list-view" class="list"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></button>
            <button id="grid-view" class="grid"><i class="fa fa-th-large"></i></button>
        </div>   
     </div> 


<div class="grid" id="grid">    
          <div class="card-deck">  

        <?php   
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($searchData); $i++) {
                $year = Schema::getyear($searchData[$i]->getyearId())->getyear();
                $src = (file_exists('video/' . $year . '/' . $searchData[$i]->getUserId() . '/' . $searchData[$i]->getFileName() . '_small.jpg')) ? 'video/' . $year . '/' . $searchData[$i]->getUserId() . '/' . $searchData[$i]->getFileName() . '_small.jpg' : 'images/MediaPortal-700-400a.jpg';

                echo <<<HTML

             <div class="item col-lg-6 col-md-6 mb-4" > 
                  <div class = "thumbnail">

                     <div class="card h-100">

                        <a href="video.php?video={$searchData[$i]->getVideoId()}"><img class="card-img-top" src={$src} alt=""></a>
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h4 class="card-title">{$searchData[$i]->getTitle()} </h4>

                            </div>

                      </div>

              </div>

       </div> 

    </div>      
      </div>

<div class="list" id="list">
        <div class="table-responsive" style="width:1000px">
           <table class="table table-striped">  
             <?php   
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($searchData); $i++) {
                $year = Schema::getyear($searchData[$i]->getyearId())->getyear();
                $src = (file_exists('video/' . $year . '/' . $searchData[$i]->getUserId() . '/' . $searchData[$i]->getFileName() . '_small.jpg')) ? 'video/' . $year . '/' . $searchData[$i]->getUserId() . '/' . $searchData[$i]->getFileName() . '_small.jpg' : 'images/MediaPortal-700-400a.jpg';

                echo <<<HTML
<tr>
                   <td>    
                   <a href="video.php?video={$searchData[$i]->getVideoId()}">{$searchData[$i]->getTitle()}{$src}</a>        
                  </td>  
                </tr>                            
HTML;
            }
           ?>
           </table>
              <!--</ul>-->
        </div>         
 </div>
   <?php   }
     ?>
        </div>
     </div>                         
</div>
```

schema.php

```
public function searchVideoCourse(string $courseNumber): ?array {
    $objectArray = [];
   if (isset($_GET['pageno'])) {
        $pageno = $_GET['pageno'];
    } else {
        $pageno = 1;
    }
    $no_of_records_per_page = 10;
    $offset = ($pageno-1) * $no_of_records_per_page;
    $conn = DatabaseConnection::getConnection();
    $total_pages_sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Video";
    $result1 = $conn->prepare($total_pages_sql);
     $total_rows = $result1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
     $total_pages = ceil($total_rows / $no_of_records_per_page);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT academicYearId, Course.courseId, date, description, fileName, isUploaded, title, userId, Video.videoId FROM Video LEFT JOIN Course ON Video.courseId = Course.courseId WHERE courseNumber = :courseNumber AND isUploaded = 1 ORDER BY Video.title ASC LIMIT $offset, $no_of_records_per_page");
    if ($stmt->execute(array(':courseNumber' => $courseNumber))) {
        while ($result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            array_push($objectArray, VideoFactory::createVideo($result['academicYearId'], $result['courseId'], $result['date'], $result['description'], $result['fileName'], $result['isUploaded'], $result['title'], $result['userId'], $result['videoId']));
        }
        return $objectArray;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

<ul class="pagination">

         <li><a href="?pageno=1">First</a></li>
        <li class="<?php if($pageno <= 1){ echo 'disabled'; } ?>">
            <a href="<?php if($pageno <= 1){ echo '#'; } else { echo "?pageno=".($pageno - 1); } ?>">Prev</a>
        </li>
        <li class="<?php if($pageno >= $total_pages){ echo 'disabled'; } ?>">
            <a href="<?php if($pageno >= $total_pages){ echo '#'; } else { echo "?pageno=".($pageno + 1); } ?>">Next</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="?pageno=<?php echo $total_pages; ?>">Last</a></li>
    </ul>
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $("#list-view").click(function() {
            $("#grid").hide();
            $("#list").show();
        });
        $("#grid-view").click(function() {
            $("#grid").show();
            $("#list").hide();
        });

    });
```

Comment: you are seeing both views because you aren't hiding one of them, as far as I can see. Maybe you should have a default view (Grid or List) and hide the other on page load.
As for the pagination part of your question, I usually do this by loading the php array into  javascript array and then call a javascript function to display a subset of the array in the DOM.

Comment: Hey, 
I'm hiding it using js. Edited it. Please check

Comment: but don't you want to hide one of them when the page loads? Choose one to hide and one to show.

Comment: yes, how do I do that?

Comment: right under your document.ready put 
$("#grid").hide();
$("#list").show();

Comment: Yes it worked.  If you put this as an answer, I'll give your answer an up-vote.  Thanks.

It would be great if you can help me with the pagination part too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put this in your document.ready block:

```
 $("#grid").hide();
 $("#list").show();
```

As stated above, to do the pagination, I would first load your dataset into an array and then call a javascript function to load parts of the array (say, the first 10 rows) into the DOM. Each button in your pager would say, in essence, "starting at record n, display the next x rows".

Comment: Hey, Yes I tried the pagination part, now I am stuck at going on to another page. The first page displays 10 videos but the next buttons doesn't work. Updating the post.

Comment: Try displaying them all on the same page. Each time you click a page number in your paginator, move your array pointer to the next (or previous) set of elements. Create your html in a javascript function and write it to the DOM, replacing what is already there.

Answer (score 1):

You should use AJAX pagination here, loading both views (List & Grid) is not a good practice, let me show you pointwise flow

- serve view buttons (List & Grid) initially and make one default view
- put "Next Button" downside
- when a user clicks on "Next Button", find his/her selected view (List & Grid) and make an AJAX request along with the selected view value
- according to the view value, you can return its relevant html codes.
- at last append response into the final container

here is a good tutorial about [ajax pagination](http://myprogrammingtutorials.com/infinite-scroll-pagination-with-php-and-ajax.html)